# How to add files ignored by a git ignore rule

Tags: git, symlink, gitignore

in my `.gitignore`, I have:

```
*.framework
*.a
```

However, I am using symlinks to these in various projects and since the symlinks and in `.a` or `.framework`, I can't seem to check those into Git.

Is there a command that I am missing or a work-a-round? I would like to check in the symlinks so that I don't have to create them each time. I could always write a bash script to make these if needed.

Comment: Note that a `.framework` is treated as a directory, so this may be as simple as using the line `*.framework/`instead (note the trailing `/`). As noted already, you may need to `rm --cached` previously committed frameworks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git only uses the path to determine whether it should or should not ignore a file - so if it's possible to derive a pattern that captures only the files you don't want and excludes all the files you do want - that's the way to go.

However, bear in mind that git ignore rules are not set in stone; it's *always* possible to add a file, you just need to use the `--force` flag:

```
$ cat .gitignore 
*.a
$ git status --ignored
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   .gitignore
# Ignored files:
#   (use "git add -f <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   bar.a
#   foo.a
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
$ git add foo.a
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
foo.a
Use -f if you really want to add them.
fatal: no files added
$
```

What seems often to be missed in this circumstance is this line in the help output:

> **Use -f if you really want to add them.**

Making use of the force option, adds the ignored file:

```
$ git add -f foo.a
$ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   foo.a
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   .gitignore
$  git status --ignored
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   foo.a
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   .gitignore
# Ignored files:
#   (use "git add -f <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   bar.a
$
```